# How can I determine if a Chrome extension is in a popup from the content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Background**

I have a Chrome extension with a browser action to launch `index.html` in a new tab.

I'd like to update the extension to open `index.html` in a [popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) first, and then include a button users can click to optionally open the app in a new tab.

I don't want this button to show when it's not a popup (since it wouldn't make sense), which means the content script needs to know whether it is a popup in order to show the button.

**Questions**

This is a two part question:

1. How does a Chrome extension popup know it's a popup?
2. How do I pass that information to a content script before the popup is rendered?

**What I've tried**

I've tried to use `chrome.extension.getViews` in `background.js` to firstly determine if a popup is open. Then, I send a message to the content script which then shows the button. However I haven't gotten it to work - `views` is always an empty array, and the message doesn't seem to ever be received by the content script.

Here are the relevant parts of my `manifest.json` file:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": {   
    "19": "img/icon19.png",
    "38": "img/icon38.png"
  },

  "default_title": "Super Simple Tasks",

  "default_popup": "index.html"
}
```

And here's what I've been trying in my `background.js`:

```
// Get all popups
var views = chrome.extension.getViews({ type: "popup" });

// Send a message if there is a popup
if (views.length > 0){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "popup_open"}, function(response) {});  
  });
};
```

And then in my content script, I listen for the message and then add a class to the body:

```
// Listen for the message
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (msg.action === 'popup_open') {
    // My code here to show the button
  }
});
```

Comment: hi, is the index.html a popup window now for your code? I think it should be a popup instead of a new tab. And if you want to just not show the button in the new tab page, you can just add a url parameter like "?ispopup=false" in the link you open new tab when click the button.

Comment: Ah thanks, a friend of mine said the same thing - the URL parameter approach works well. I've added it as an answer!

Comment: Simply include it as a url parameter to the popup

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After talking with a friend I discovered an elegant solution that doesn't involve messaging or even a `background.js` script at all.

I can specify `?popup=true` in `manifest.json` and check for that parameter in my extension's content script. Here's the code:

`manifest.json` now looks like this:

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": {   
    "19": "img/icon19.png",
    "38": "img/icon38.png"
  },

  "default_title": "Super Simple Tasks",

  "default_popup": "index.html?popup=true"
}
```

The following code in my content script (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery)) checks for `?popup=true`. Worth noting that this function can handle multiple URL parameters split by the `&` character.

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
      return sParameterName[1];
    }
  }
}

var isPopup;
isPopup = getUrlParameter('popup') === 'true';
```

Finally, add a class to the body if it's a popup:

```
$('body').toggleClass('popup', isPopup)
```

Answer (score 7):

In the manifest file add a hash to the url:

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "index.html#popup"
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
if (location.hash === '#popup') 
    // do something awesome!
```

Comment: One minor adjustment: it should be if (location.hash == '#popup')

Comment: This should be bumped as it is simpler than accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

I needed something similar as i wanted to create some cross-compatible code for all script types.

I found that this worked quite well.

```
const SCRIPT_TYPE = (() => {
    if (chrome && chrome.extension && chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage && chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() === window) {
        return 'BACKGROUND';
    } else if (chrome && chrome.extension && chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage && chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() !== window) {
        return 'POPUP';
    } else if (!chrome || !chrome.runtime || !chrome.runtime.onMessage) {
        return 'WEB';
    } else {
        return 'CONTENT';
    }
})();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this can't tell the difference between the popup and an extension page like moz-extension://hash

Comment: This is absolutely great. Thanks for sharing this. One thing though - Isn't WEB same same as CONTENT_SCRIPT ( or what is web here ? ) and also what about OPTIONS page ?

Comment: @bhavya_w this would be if you were also injecting the script into the actual WEBPAGE using a script tag or eval. I am not sure about OPTIONS.

Answer (score 2):

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
    if(tab == undefined)
        document.getElementById('mButton').style.display = 'inline-block';
});
```

I initially set the button's `display: none;` if the returned tab is `undefined`, means it's not a tab (so it is popup) and then I display button. You can reverse it of course.

**======**

Well the sending parameter also works, which in that case you won't need to add the query string in the manifest, just adding it in button's click listener would suffice.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "index.html?popup=false"});
});
```

And then the same process (reading the query string and comparing, etc).

**======**

Alternatively you can make a copy of `index.html` say `index2.html`, remove the button from index.html, use index2.html in the manifest and index.html for button click. :)